# Chrome: http://localhost:3000/ - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm reading David Turnbull's fantastic Your First Meteor Application. In his book, he uses the JavaScript console in Chrome to explain points, and I'd love to follow along.  However, when I try and run http://localhost:3000/ I get the following error:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

It works perfectly in Firefox and Safari. I'm using a Mac with OS X Yosemite.

I've googled, but nothing suggested on internet works.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's helpful to post what you've tried, so that we don't suggest things that haven't worked for you. Have you seen this? https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2601

Comment: @ChristianVarga The OP clearly stated what he tried!

Comment: Is chrome set up to use a particular proxy? Are you sure the URL is identical?

Comment: Tx for the fast response :) @ChristianVarga I'll look at the github

Comment: @ChristianVarga I was refering to his setup and the fact that other browsers have no issue connecting. There obviously is nothing the OP can find "on the internet" which solves this. So that is irrelevant. The OP stated the situation to its full extent. That is what I meant.

Comment: I tried all of the steps here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/117805?hl=en

Comment: can you try using http://127.0.0.1:3000/ ?

Comment: You can use firefox's console too, it does the same thing, send commands.

Comment: hey that works @KyleMit . Funny though I tried that before but I think somewhere in my attempts i changed something that allowed 127.0.0.1:300 to work.

Answer (score 0):

[`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is a magic string that should do a local DNS lookup which routes to an IPv4 address of `127.0.0.1` or an IPv6 address of `::1`

If you look at your `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` you should see the following:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
::1          localhost
```

If you're having trouble with the string in some browser (perhaps because of IP address versioning) you can always type in the IP address directly without needing to go through the DNS entry to get there.

So instead of:

http://localhost:3000/

Try using:

http://127.0.0.1:3000/